# Convert form control value to string

Tags: angular, forms, type-conversion

Hey I created an input field as form control.
The input value will be added to a formArray everytime user enters the message.

```
export class AppComponent { 
      inputText = this.fb.control('', Validators.required);
      inputArray = this.fb.array([]);

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
      


     
   

     **text:string;**
            public addInputIntoArr() {
                      this.inputArray.push(this.fb.control(this.inputText.value));
**this.text=this.inputText.value;**
    this.inputText.reset();
                
            }
```

HTML:

```
<textarea
                matInput             
                [formControl]="inputText"
                required=""
                (keyup.enter)=addInputIntoArr()
            >
            </textarea>
```

For a function I need the value of the input field as type string.
I tried this:

```
this.inputText.value
```

But I get the information that type string is required.
Now to my question, is it possible to convert a form control value to type string and if yes, how can this be done.

I would be very gratefult for any answers and look forward to learning new things.

Solved:
I created a variable to store this.inputText.value, I then use the value of this variable in the function instead of inputText.value. It is working fine, but I am not sure if this is best case. This is what I come up with, if anyone has other ideas or approach I will be glad to hear :)

Comment: Did you tried with `this.inputText.value`? FormControl values will always be `any` as [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) this link shows.

Comment: Yes I tried it, unfortunately it still not accepts it as string

Comment: Use `''+this.inputText.value` but really I feel that is strange the information you get :(

Comment: When I'm using ''+this.inputText.value I am getting null as inputText. When using this.inputText.value I am getting following error :Error: `event.text` is required. I found it as well confusing because when I log typeof inputText.value, I get string..

Comment: Try to declare your inputText as `inputText  = new FormControl('', Validators.required);`. I had problems with `this.fb.control` too and it solved my problems.

Comment: I tried this too, still get the same error :(

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not need a complete form but just one formControl (judging from your example), please try this:

in your ts class:

```js
inputText = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

You can then access the value with this.inputText.value,
You can also listen to changes:

```js
this.inputText.valueChanges.subscribe({
    next: value => doSomethingWith(value),
    error: () => handleError
});
```

(Do not forget to unsubscribe later.)

In your template, you can remove `required=""`

You can also apply styling for an invalid textfield (like a red border) by referring to inputText.invalid in your template to create/refer to a class,
e.g.:

```js
[ngClass]="{'border-red': inputText.invalid}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access the value with this.inputText.value. Maybe it is important to notice, that I need this value for another function where I wanted to use the input value. The variable in this function must be a string, so I tried access it with this.inputText.value but I get the error: Error: `event.text` is required..

Comment: I also used this but get null  JSON.stringify(this.inputText.value)

Comment: has you a "variable" or a template reference variable with the same name: `inputText`?  BTW I don't know any event with property "text"

Comment: did you leave the (keyup.enter)=addInputIntoArr() in the template? i suggest you remove it since it might cause the problem and add the inputText values inside the this.inputText.valueChanges subscription